# UIWebView in UITableView cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiwebview

I need to have UITableView with dynamic cells, and each cell should contain UIWebView in it.

I'm using this to show an iFrame from a different source for each entry. Each entry points to different links and each UIWebView need to be updated from time to time. Also some links may point to empty pages which I would like to check then remove.

Of course it's not a good idea to send request each time when user scrolls the table, so I would like to have a cache and update WebViews with a "refresh all" request.

So I've added UIWebView to Cell.xib file, linked it to Cell class (as weak) and created webViewArray:

```
var bannerWebViewsArray = [String: bannerWebViewObject]()
```

It's a kind of array of dictionaries where key (String) is an entry id (which is also used as WebView.tag which is then used in WebView delegate methods), and bannerWebViewObject is a structure with UIWebView and more fields for deep checks.

So when I send loadRequest from webView in specific cell first (in cellForRowAtIndexPath), I copy it to array:

```
cell?.bannerWebView.delegate = self
cell?.bannerWebView.tag = Int(entryId)!
cell?.bannerWebView.loadRequest(NSMutableURLRequest(URL: *some_url*))
bannerWebViewsArray[entry.entryId!]?.bannerWebView = (cell?.bannerWebView)!
```

And later, if page is ok, I just load it from array back:

```
cell?.bannerWebView = bannerWebViewsArray[entry.entryId!]?.bannerWebView
```

Also there are a lot of triggers and checks in order to skip webview sometimes, check loaded page etc.

But when I scroll the table and later come back, sometimes an empty web view is placed into a cell, and after more scrolling some WebViews disappear while others will be shown again.

I've tried to remove "weak" for IBOutlet, but it did not help. Also I've tried to use unique identifier for each cell, but not sure that it is a good idea and it also does not work (webviews are always empty)

So what is the best practice for using UIWebViews in UITableViewCell? Is it possible to store them in an array and later load from it each time a user scrolls the table? Otherwise it will be too many requests to server

Looking forward for your help and will provide more info if needed.